# Why does my GPIO only show 2V when connected to the Gate Termina lof NTE2390?

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi, gpio

I've got a circuit set up with a motor that matches [this diagram](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/N-channel-MOSFET-switch-circuit.php).

When a 3 V power supply is connected to the Gate terminal, the motor spins.
However, when I replace the 3V supply at the Gate terminal with a GPIO pin that I've measured to be 3.3 V when I turn it on, the motor doesn't spin when I turn on the GPIO pin.

Further measurements showed that when the GPIO is hooked up the Gate terminal of the MOSFET, it only achieves 2 V when turned on.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `when I turn on the GPIO pin` .... are you sure that you are doing that? .... think about this .... what other modes (functions) does the GPIO pin have? .... could you possibly be setting the wrong mode for the  pin?

Comment: Please add a schematic of your actual circuit. It may well be you don't have a common ground between MCU and motor.

Comment: FYI: Latest version of Raspberry Pi do not use GPIO.setup() or GPIO.setmode() I use var=Button() to set a pin as an input. I use var=LED() or var = PWMLED() to preset the pin as an output. Dougie Lawson at Raspberry.org is constantly updating the gpiozero and guizero code. Also check that you have a ground return to pin 39 on the header (GND)

Comment: @jsotola, Yes, I measured the voltage to ground to be 3.3 if and only if I turn it on.

Comment: @sstobbe, what software do you typically use to make such diagrams? I'm new to this field.

Comment: There is a schematic editor builtin into the site "Circuit Lab", otherwise LTSpice or Ki-cad are good tools to start experimenting with.

Comment: Google low-side n-channel mosfet motor driver for the proper way to connect your Pi to the circuit. Without a proper schematic from you I can only guess that you might have the gate directly wired to the GPIO pin without current limiting or a pull down resistor. Do you have a flyback diode wired in too?